# Which visa do I need for a 14-week bootcamp in the USA?

Tags: visas, usa, study, portuguese-citizens

I'm a Portuguese citizen and I'm thinking to participate in a 14-week (98 days) computer science bootcamp in the US (Coding Dojo). Portugal is a country included in the Visa Waiver Program (VWP) however this program is only valid for stays of 90 days or less without first obtaining a visa and is not valid when you want to study there.

What visa should I get to go there?

Comment: @pnuts Will a bootcamp qualify?

Comment: I would call the CBP (US border police) and ask if I were you: 1-202-325-8000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Department of State website](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/study-exchange/student.html), you will need a M-1 visa. Indeed, it sounds like your training matches the following description:

> Vocational or other recognized nonacademic institution, other than a language training program

Note that if it is your main purpose of travel, the VWP program is not the right choice. The B visa might or might not be the right choice, the website is unclear (and @Dennis comment shows it might be the right choice):

> Citizens of Visa Waiver Program (VWP) participating countries who intend to study cannot travel on the VWP or on visitor (B) visas, except to undertake recreational study as part of a tourist visit.
>
> Enrollment in a short recreational course of study, which is not for credit toward a degree or academic certificate, is permitted on a visitor (B) visa.

Comment: My nephew has attended a 3 week coding boot camp in each of the past several summers and has entered as a B visitor for that purpose without difficulty. If the camp is not SEVP-accredited he can't get an M-1 and a B visa is the only possibility he has.

Comment: @Dennis is your son a citizen of a Visa Waiver Program participating country?

Comment: The entire point of the system is that they want international students to attend certified programs. That's why the certification program exists. Whether or not you can get away with doing it on a tourist visa is not for me to say, but it's certainly not how this is supposed to work.

Comment: No, my nephew is visa-exempt and hence is treated more or less like he has a B visa in his passport at the border. The OP would need to apply for a B visa for a 14 week stay in any case, so he wouldn't be relying on the VWP either.

Comment: Judged from the curriculum the only difference between the 3 and 14 week boot camps is 11 weeks. One is allowed to take a course on a B-2 if the sole purpose is the sheer pleasure of taking the course, and if the school can't provide an I-20 the only way the OP can attend is by applying for a B visa for the purpose and letting the visa officer decide if the course is suitable for that visa.

Comment: [This would seem to prohibit taking such a course on a B visa](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/students-and-exchange-visitors/students-and-employment/special-instructions-b-1b-2-visitors-who-want-enroll-school): "The regulations, at 8 CFR 214.2(b)(7), specifically prohibit study in the United States while in B-1 or B-2 status." Some incidental study [might be allowed](https://www.ice.gov/doclib/sevis/pdf/Nonimmigrant%20Class%20Who%20Can%20Study.pdf), but here your primary purpose would be coming to the US to study. I believe you'd need a SEVP-certified school.

Comment: @ZachLipton, note the quote from your second reference is "Visitors may, however, engage in study that is avocational or recreational in nature.", so it is the nature of the study that matters. This can be a fuzzy distinction when the course provides no academic credit nor vocational certification, so what is acceptable in practice can be determined only from what border officers actually do. I know an unobfuscated "I am visiting the US for 3 weeks to attend this coding boot camp" can get you a B-2 stamp since I've seen exactly that.

Comment: @Dennis Sure. "I want to come as a tourist and see New York and while I'm there I'm going to take a short flower arranging class for fun" is very different from coming for the primary purpose of taking a 14 week course that costs tens of thousands of dollars designed to get you a job. It is, of course, possible they let it slide, but it's also possible to have your visa application refused because you're coming to study and not for tourism and then never be eligible to use the VWP again. which would be rather inconvenient.